# How can I travel to Jamaica with an expired Jamaican passport? What document/permission can I get from the consulate, USICS or whomever?

Tags: passports, us-permanent-residents, jamaican-citizens

I have an expired [Jamaican](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaica) passport and a family emergency. My grandmother died and the funeral is the 23rd of March. However, my ticket has already been booked for the 22nd which is her set up day. I have not been back to Jamaica for 5 years, and this is my first travel since leaving.

Is it possible for me to travel with my expired passport since it’s a Jamaican passport and I’m going to Jamaica? Also, since I would be there for 10 days I would renew it.

I tried calling all the three different Jamaican consulates. I emailed them, but they did not respond. I’m not surprised.

How long would it take me to get an Emergency Certificate (EC)? I am also a permanent resident in America.

I tried talking to the airline, but they’re not sure either. They just told me the answer they saw on the Internet.

What documents or approval could I get saying *Yes, I could travel.*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen You don't need to provide citations for your copy edits

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- - he doesn't need to, but it is useful

Answer (score 30):

As a citizen of Jamaica, you can enter Jamaica with an expired passport.  So you don't need the consulate, you need to **call your airline** and confirm that *they* will also let you board with an expired passport, because otherwise you're not getting on that plane.

You also need to double-check:

- How long it will take to get a new passport in Jamaica (10 days sounds kinda tight?)
- That you bring all the documentation needed to get a new passport, and
- What steps, if any, you need to take to notify the US about your new passport

Comment: A US PR doesn't need a passport to enter the US, only the PR card. See here: https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1191?language=en_US. Whether the OP can leave Jamaica without a valid passport is another issue...